# Excel - Rank data ascending only if >500 and exclude blanks

Tags: excel, rank

```
Rank    name    Total   Failures
  2     Gary    4165    200
        Stand   410     10
  1     Plag    502     23
        Monk    ""      ""
  3     Terry   5000    2100
```

Hiyas, what I'm struggling to achieve is ranking and excluding blanks.Ascending. 
Totals and Failures are VLOOKUP formulas.

What I'm looking to do is Rank on failures if total > 500 or is not "" then rank. Above is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to have a dummy column that only picks up the Total when your conditions are met, and then rank on that instead.

Edit: countifs may also work. See here: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2017/03/09/excel-rank-formula-example/

Comment: You're right, that was extremely simple. I think I was trying to over complicate it. Basically IF(Total>=500,Failures,"") and then rank the results. Thanks!